# VBA passing listbox to a function

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to populate a listbox by passing my listbox object to a subfunction, but whenever I run it I get a type mismatch error. I pass the object MAIN.BoxY1 to the function FillListBox, where MAIN is the codename for the sheet the listbox is on, and BoxY1 is my listbox name (ActiveX). When I alter the FillListBox function to include MAIN.BoxY1 instead of MyBox for every instance it will work fine. What is the proper method of passing a listbox to another function?

```
Sub FillListBox(MyBox As ListBox, DataList As Variant)
    MyBox.MultiSelect = 1
    For j = 1 To NumOutputs
        MyBox.AddItem DataList(j)
    Next j
End Sub

Sub BoxY1_Fill()
    FillListBox MAIN.BoxY1, TheData
End Sub
```

Comment: Not a perfect fix, but have you tried accepting that argument as an Object instead of Listbox ?  Sub FillListBox(MyBox as Object, DataList as variant) ? Also, maybe specify you are passing it by reference not by value?  Sub FillListBox(ByRef MyBox as Object, DataList as variant) ?

Comment: That indeed works; thanks for your suggestion although I still can't understand why a ListBox object didn't, but perhaps I will find out one day.

Comment: Glad it helped - the answer below looks good, that's information I didn't know - would be interested to see if that fixes it , i've run into similar problems too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two types of listbox in Excel: the "built-in" type and the ActiveX version.  Depending on which type you are dealing with, you need to set up your function parameter differently:

```
Sub Testing()
    test1 Sheet1.ListBox1                            ' <<ActiveX Listbox
    test2 Sheet1.ListBoxes("ListBox2")               ' <<Forms Listbox
    test2 Sheet1.Shapes("ListBox2").OLEFormat.Object ' <<Forms Listbox (avoiding 
                                                     '   deprecated 'Listboxes')
End Sub

'ActiveX listbox
Function test1(lb As msforms.ListBox)
    Debug.Print lb.ListCount
End Function

'Forms listbox
Function test2(lb As ListBox)
    Debug.Print lb.ListCount
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am indeed using ActiveX. Is there any advantage to using one over the other?

Comment: Depends on what functionality you need.  I seem to have more rendering issues with ActiveX so tend to avoid those on worksheets...

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have already had rendering problems with the highlighting. I went with ActiveX because it seemed easy to give it a codename. Can the same be done with an excel forms listbox? I.e. how would I name it 'BoxY1'?

Comment: You name it using the "Name Box" to the left of the formula bar. Don't forget to hit Enter to "commit" the new name.

Comment: Thanks. I'm generally becoming quite frustrated with the lack of documentation on listboxes, and particularly the lack of distinction made between the syntax used for the forms version vs. the ActiveX controls. Is there a good reference source for either?

Comment: I'm also curious what you mean by saying that ListBoxes() is deprecated. Is that an old function that is no longer in use?

Comment: `ListBoxes()` is deprecated in the sense that it still works, but its use is discouraged as there's no guarantee that it won't suddenly stop working one or two releases down the line.  If you try searching 'ListBoxes' in the Object Browser you'll get no hits, unless you right-click in the OB pane and select `Show Hidden Members` from the right-click menu.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for your answer, I was facing same issu as in this post, reading your answer I got it work. Before I read your answer I was passing it as object not as msforms.ListBox, because simple ListBox wasn't working...I would like to ask you, for all active X controls we should use msforms.(controltype) ? or only for listbox ? I am asking, because I have an active x combobox, I pass it as combobox not as msforms.combobox, and i don't have any error

Comment: @JustGreat   Sorry I can't answer that - I only tested the listbox when I answered this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MSForms.ListBox

```
Sub FillListBox(MyBox As MSForms.ListBox, DataList As Variant)
```